# Set Google Chrome Window to a Variable

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I'm trying to open a Google Chrome window, and continue to use that window to do many things. Which means I need to set it to a variable. Is there anyway to do this?

I have the following code to open the Google Chrome window and navigate to a URL, but I need to do more than that.

```
Sub Test()

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://google.ca")

End Sub
```

I want to type in my username and password, hit the submit button to log in, and do other things. Is there a way I can reference the chrome window like I could in Internet Explorer? (by using Set IE = ...)

Comment: Look at using selenium basic vba

Comment: @QHarr  I looked into that, and I unfortunately cannot download anything, as this is a work computer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us know exactly what you are trying to do in google chrome from excel.

If you are trying to send key commands you can try to use:

```
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://google.ca")

Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
```

etc. etc. etc.

Hope this helps!